# OpenGL ES watercolor brush effect

Tags: opengl-es

On the left is what we have now, and on the right what we are trying to achieve. Currently, the line is in one solid color with transparency.

Should we draw a pattern image as an overlay above or brush image should be already with such pattern? 
Could you please advice a direction on where to look and what to try?

[image: Watercolor brushes]

Brush image that is used is on the left, and watercolor pattern that possibly could be used is on the right.

[image: Patterns]

The following code is used to draw a line with brush texture using the stencil buffer to avoid textures transparency overlap:

```
        glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT.gluint)

        glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST.gluint)
        glStencilOp(GL_KEEP.gluint, GL_KEEP.gluint, GL_REPLACE.gluint)

        glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL.gluint, 1, 1)
        glStencilMask(1)

        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS.gluint, 0, count.int32)

        glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST.gluint)
```

Comment: For the brush you use a mask with the information transparent (alpha=0) or opaque (alpha=1). Why do you not use a mask with a noise in the alpha channel, 0  for transparent area and arbitrary values between >0.0 and 1.0 for the brush?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I mask black color in code, so a result brush texture is with transparency alpha = 0 (I've updated an image in the post). So do you suggest to make a brush image with noise initially and just use it for the brush?